# Create photo album in facebook using android and Graph api

Tags: android

We have a problem creating photo album in facebook using android and graph API. We already have been able to upload photos to facebook using Graph API. We are using following for uploading a photo to facebook.

Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("method", "photos.upload");
params.putString("title", uploadFile.getName());
params.putString("privacy", "{'value':'EVERYONE'}");

facebook.request("https://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=photos.upload",params,"POST");

Please let us know if anybody aware of. We have searched a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the working solution for the above problem.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("name", albumName);
String response = mFacebook.request("https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums",params,"POST");
String albumId=Util.parseJson(response).getString("id");
```

Above code will help create a new photo album with the **albumName** and return the album id generated by facebook.